# How to find numbers and remove them from a multidimensional array?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a Bingo game to play with my family and I would like to know what is the best way to remove numbers that have been called and then create another array with the tickets that is empty - so I know they have already win.

So far I made this array (I reduced it to make easier to understand):

```
var tickets = [
     ['T1',1,2,8,10,23,18,44],
     ['T2',2,3,3,6,45,12,55],
     ['T3',4,7,10,42,55,45,60],
     ['T4',3,5,3,6,55,68,85],
     ['T5',1,4,3,6,66,74,80],
 ];
```

All the other part of bingo is done, I just need to realize how can I know the tickets that have finished already to make easier to validate the winners.

Comment: Simple loop that checks to see if each index of the array exists in another array. Using filter you can get the boards that have winners.

Comment: Hi Robert Alexander, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take a moment to read through the article on [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), especially the link regarding including a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have an array of numbers that have been already called?
If so:

```js
var called = [1,2,8,10,23,18,44];
var tickets = [
     ['T1',1,2,8,10,23,18,44],
     ['T2',2,3,3,6,45,12,55],
     ['T3',4,7,10,42,55,45,60],
     ['T4',3,5,3,6,55,68,85],
     ['T5',1,4,3,6,66,74,80]
 ];
// Gets tickets with called numbers removed

tickets = tickets.map(x => x.filter(x => !called.includes(x)));
console.log(tickets);

// Gets winners

var winners = tickets.map(x => x.length === 1 ? x : []).flatMap(x=>x)

console.log(winners);

// You should really use objects here but you decided multidimentional arrays, Example of an object
/*
{
  'T1': [1,2,8,10,23,18,44],
  'T2': [2,3,3,6,45,12,55],
  'T3': [4,7,10,42,55,45,60],
  'T4': [3,5,3,6,55,68,85],
  'T5': [1,4,3,6,66,74,80]
}
*/
```

```css
/* this is to make the SO console bigger */

.as-console-wrapper{max-height: none !important;height:100% !important}
```

Comment: Amazing! That was exactly what I needed. Worked really fined. Thank you very much, Eli Ozcan!